# how can I get the IPs list reffering to an FQDN

Tags: c++, linux, ip, fqdn

In my C++ linux application how can I get the IPs list reffering to an FQDN?
(static IPs + dynamic IPs)

10x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no principal difference between retrieving the mapping for a local and a fully qualified domain name. Therefore, you can call the [getaddrinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) as you would with any other domain name. Note that there is no way to get the list of all IP addresses associated to a domain name because DNS servers are free to advertise only certain addresses or pick a few from a larger list. For example, `google.com` will usually map to servers on your continent.

Here's an example on how to use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 const char* domain = argc>1 ? argv[1] : "example.com";
 struct addrinfo *result, *rp, hints;

 memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
 hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // TCP

 int tmp = getaddrinfo(domain, NULL, &hints, &result);
 if (tmp != 0) {
  fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(tmp));
  return 1;
 }

 for (rp = result;rp != NULL;rp = rp->ai_next) {
  char buf[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
  switch (rp->ai_family) {
  case AF_INET:{
   struct in_addr* a4 = & ((struct sockaddr_in*) rp->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
   inet_ntop(rp->ai_family, a4, buf, sizeof(buf));
   printf("IPv4: %s\n", buf);
   break;}
  case AF_INET6:{
   struct in6_addr* a6 = & ((struct sockaddr_in6*) rp->ai_addr)->sin6_addr;
   inet_ntop(rp->ai_family, a6, buf, sizeof(buf));
   printf("IPv6: %s\n", buf);
   break;
  }}
 }

 freeaddrinfo(result);
 return 0;
}
```

This will output:

```
IPv6: 2620:0:2d0:200::10
IPv4: 192.0.32.10
```

Comment: can you please attach code example for the FQDN: aaa.bbb.com?

Comment: @gln Did, but with the generic example.com, since aaa.bbb.com would just result in a boring error message

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the getHostByName() function in the C++ sockets library. ([here is an example](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/gethostbynameman.html))

It will give you back a hostent struct, from which you can get information like IP.